# Why is the total derivative of a one dimensional solution to the wave equation zero?

Tags: partial-derivative, wave-equation

Page 23 below is from Garrity's book "Electricity and Magnetism for Mathematicians".  He is discussing how changing to a coordinate frame moving with some speed relative to the original coordinate frame results in our solution to the one dimensional wave equation having a corresponding change in speed.

However, in the discussion, he uses a fact I don't understand.  If y(x,t) is our solution to the one dimensional wave equation, then why should 0 = dy/dt?  Please see picture below.  Thanks for the help!

It seems like dy/dt = 0 because we are restricting attention to just values of x and t that give us y0 = y(x,t).  If this is the case, then our result is only valid for those special x and t values?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems he's trying to derive the wave equation. He's doing that by "following" a point on a wavefront, and showing how the derivatives of are then related.

Here's what's happening: he has some function $y(x,t)$ which tells us the amplitute at a specific place $x$ and time $t$. Then he's asking us to follow, say, the node of a wave over time. This corresponds to setting $y(x,t)=y_0$. Then we no longer have $x$ and $t$ as independent variables; rather $x$ secretly depends on $t$, through the function $y$. Then we can take derivatives of both sides with respect to $t$. Clearly the derivative of the right side is $0$, which is what that first line says. Then the derivative of the second side is found using the chain rule. From this, and the fact that given these constraints $\partial x/\partial t$ is the velocity of the wave, you can derive the equation at the bottom.

All of this math is meant to constrain the form that $y$ can take, if we want it to represent a wave.

Answer (score 1):

Don't ask me why, but he writes that $y(x,t)=y_0$ the the line $x=x_0+vt$. Since $y_0$ is a constant with respect to $t$, so must be $y(x_0+vt,t)$.